# Right-alignment constraints?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, constraints

I'm trying to add constraints to right-align a button to its parent view, but having some problems. In the following image, I've created left-aligned constraints for the `<` button. The `Play` button is center aligned, independent of the `<` button.

[image]

I've tried adding a constraint for the `Reload` button to be right aligned, but it sets a fixed distance which doesn't align but rather creates a fixed position. Not sure what I'm missing here.

[image]

I've updated this question with an image of the existing constraints.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you been using "Trailing Space to Container"? If this doesn't work you will need to check:

- Which view is the container of your Reload button to ensure it isn't aligning with the wrong view
- That the container view has the bounds you expect it to have

If you need further help, could you please upload your view hierarchy, like so:
[image]

Also the existing contraints on the reload button would be helpful so we can eliminate any interaction between constraints :)

Comment: Updated the question with an image of my current constraints. As best as I can tell, I'm using trailing space on the Reload button to the its parent view "Controls View". I removed and re-added the button to be sure and I still get the same behavior.

Comment: Your constraints look all right to me! I'm assuming the Controls View is the yellow part? If not try to add a color to its background to ensure it's rendering at the same size you expect :)

Comment: Yup Controls View is yellow. Its constraints to the super view work as expected, I think. If I change the constants on its restraints, the `<>` and `Play` buttons reposition themselves accordingly. Just `Reload` that isn't.